# Git show is left behind in some obscure way

Tags: git

I do on git version 1.8.3.1

```
git checkout develop --
git fetch origin develop
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git diff FETCH_HEAD HEAD
git diff
```

The diffs show no differences .. good.
If I edit my file then it is the same as in GitLab on the remote .. good.

If I do

```
git show origin/develop:<my file>
```

then I see an earlier version.

I get the same for

```
git show remotes/origin/develop:<my file>
```

Comment: 1.8? You mean the one that was released in 2012 and last updated in 2014?

Comment: First, upgrade Git to make sure this isn't a bug in a quite old version of Git.

Comment: Check what FETCH_HEAD, origin/develop, and remotes/origin/develop point at with `git rev-parse`. Check if you have a local branch named `origin/develop` with `git branch`.

Comment: For software as unreliable as git it it hard to justify the risk in upgrading.

Comment: Your version is 10 years old. There have been 37 releases and far more testing since. The newer versions are much more reliable. Software releases aren't wine, they don't get better with age.

Comment: There is no local branch called orgin/develop.

git rev-parse origin/develop 
git rev-parse remotes/origin/develop 

both point at the same commit.

git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD 

points at a different commit

git rev-parse origin/develop :<my file>

points at a different commit (a third one)

Comment: And you expect `develop` to be at `origin/develop`?

Comment: "For software as unreliable as git it it hard to justify the risk in upgrading" Yes, one definitely wouldn't repair a broken car, because the car is broken.

Comment: You obviously have a lot of faith in your car mechanic / dealer -- matt

Answer (score 1):

> `git rev-parse origin/develop` and `git rev-parse remotes/origin/develop` both point at the same commit. `git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD` points at a different commit.

You used `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` as a surrogate for `git reset --hard origin/devleop` but, for whatever reason, `FETCH_HEAD` was not at `origin/develop`.

`FETCH_HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` change with the last command and can change out from under you. Use `git reset --hard origin/develop` to be sure.

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git diff FETCH_HEAD HEAD
```

Note that this check is tautological. If you just reset your current branch (`develop`) to FETCH_HEAD it will be at FETCH_HEAD. If you expect your current checkout to be at origin/develop check `git diff origin/develop`.

Use `git log --graph --decorate` to see the true state of your repository and what commits `develop` and `origin/develop` point at.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

> git version 1.8.3.1 ...
>
> ```
> git fetch origin develop
> ```

Running:

```
git fetch origin
```

on Git 1.8.3.1 will do what you want, but running:

```
git fetch origin develop
```

on Git 1.8.3.1 won't, because [the action you wish to have happen was not put into Git until 1.8.4](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b80121027d1247a0754b3cc46897fee75c050b44/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L226-L232).

You can run:

```
git fetch origin develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

if you're unwilling to just run:

```
git fetch origin
```

for some reason.  Or, of course, you can upgrade Git (you really should upgrade to at least Git 2.23, to get the new `git switch` and `git restore` commands).